# How can I automatically disable AJAX on local links which do not have a mobile-suitable view?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-mobile

I am using Jquery Mobile to build a mobile version of an existing ASP.NET mvc3 site.

The way I am doing this is by detecting in my controllers if the page is being requested by a mobile or not and then providing a mobile-suited mvc view if there is one and providing the standard view if there isn't.

The problem I am having is that links to pages which do not have a suitable view still get Ajaxed into the page by jquery-mobile, messing up the layout.  I know you can disable this functionality on a link-by-link basis by using data-ajax="false", however I do not have control over each link as it is a CMS-based site so there is nothing to stop the user from linking to a page within the site that does not have a mobile view.

What I was hoping I could do is maybe include an attribute in the base view of the desktop version of the site which jquery mobile would pick up when it attempts to ajax load the page, rejecting it and reloading the link without ajax. Is this possible?

Comment: $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
        $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false
    })

Comment: That would disable ajax linking for the entire mobile site would it not? I still want to use it except for when a page shouldn't be ajaxed.

Comment: if ($.mobile) window.location = '/no-mobile.html'; ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the time being I've done this:

```
$(document).bind("pageload", function (event, data) {
    if ($("div[data-role=\"content\"]", data.xhr.responseText).length < 1) {
       window.location = data.url;                  
    } 
});
```

I'm checking that the loaded page contains jQuery mobile element data-role="content" and if it doesn't, redirecting the browser to the page proper.  It's not ideal though since I'm parsing the html of every page on load. It also means that the non-mobile site is loaded into jquery mobile, and then loaded again on the redirect (although this shouldn't happen too often in this site).

I also had to add an empty hidden div with data-role="page" on the master view of the desktop version of the site because jquery mobile still tries to transition to the non-mobile site before the window.location kicks in and I couldn't work out how to prevent that.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest rendering a combination of some localised JS and ViewBag properties to handle the problem per page, otherwise you'll end up with a scenario where you'll have to apply 'data-ajax="false"' everywhere, which isn't pretty.

Aside from your controller code which could be user agent detection to populate the "ViewBag.IsMobileDevice" property, something like the following may help you out:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $( document ).bind( "mobileinit", function( event, data ){
        if ((/iphone|ipod|ipad.*os 5/gi).test(navigator.appVersion) && @ViewBag.IsMobileDevice) {
            $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
        }
    });

</script>
```

Please note that I'm using iphone/ipad/ipod as an example, but you could use anything in it's place depending on your requirements. I'd look into [51degrees.mobi](http://51degrees.codeplex.com/) for some inspiration on mobile detection.

I hope this helps you out or at least points you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the reply although I don't think it will solve my problem. 

My MVC site outputs either a mobile view or a desktop view depending on device.  

I'm not having problems detecting device, but the problem is, not all pages have both a mobile and desktop view.  Jquery mobile still tries to ajax the page in if it doesn't have a mobile view.

Comment: Hi @pantryfight **Should** be fairly straight forward then, if you already know which pages shouldn't be marked up, then simply replace the "if" statement in the code block above with the ViewBag.IsMobileDevice (or whatever) only.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your response but this will disable ajax for the page won't it?

What I'm trying to do is not that, but to prevent that page from getting Ajaxed in in the first place.

Comment: This will not disable ajax for the page, only the links. if you look at the JQM documentation [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/globalconfig.html) the documentation states _jQuery Mobile will automatically handle link clicks and form submissions through Ajax, when possible. If false, URL hash listening will be disabled as well, and URLs will load as ordinary HTTP requests._

Comment: What I think you're trying to achieve is not disabling ajaxing links, but you want JQM to not enhance your markup at all, which would be achieved by replacing the "$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;" in the code block above with "$.mobile.ignoreContentEnabled = true"

Answer (score 0):

The URL's which don't have a mobile view, you can give a separate class to it, say ".no-mobi-view" and then before the pagecreate event, you can write a javascript code to add the attribute data

```
$( document ).live( "pagebeforecreate", function( event){
    $('.no-mobi-view').attr("data-ajax","false");
});
```

It may be dependent on CMS, but probably you can filter the cms output before it is being sent to the browser. instead of a class you can test for `target=_blank`